# Zeit now deployment sh: build: command not found

Tags: reactjs, typescript, deployment, vercel

I get this error when I trying to deploy a React app(typescript) to zeit. I'm running MacOS Mojave, node v12.12.0, npm 6.14.2(but I use yarn in the project, yarn 1.17.3). It's from a template, I just run `yarn` then `now`. And the now console give me a link to this log error.  have no idea what it's referring to.

```
sh: build: command not found
Error: Exited with 127
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/zeit/ab5350c9de262234/.build-utils/.builder/node_modules/@now/static-build/dist/index.js:33891:24)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
worker exited with code 20 and signal null
Done with "package.json"
```

The package.json file:

```
{
 "name": "@pickbazar/admin",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
   "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3",
   "apexcharts": "3.8.6",
   "apollo-boost": "^0.4.4",
   "baseui": "^9.40.0",
   "formik": "^2.1.4",
   "fuse.js": "^3.4.6",
   "graphql": "^14.6.0",
   "mobile-detect": "^1.4.4",
   "moment": "^2.24.0",
   "react": "^16.12.0",
   "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.3",
   "react-content-loader": "^5.0.1",
   "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
   "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
   "react-dropzone": "^10.2.1",
   "react-flexbox-grid": "^2.1.2",
   "react-hook-form": "4.9.3",
   "react-image": "^2.4.0",
   "react-moment": "^0.9.6",
   "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
   "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
   "react-scripts": "^3.4.0",
   "styled-components": "^5.0.1",
   "styletron-engine-atomic": "^1.4.5",
   "styletron-react": "^5.2.7",
   "typescript": "^3.7.5",
   "yup": "^0.28.1"
 },

"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"admin-dev": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"serve": "serve -s build"
 },
 "eslintConfig": {
   "extends": "react-app"
 },
 "browserslist": [
   ">0.2%",
   "not dead",
   "not ie <= 11",
   "not op_mini all"
 ],
 "devDependencies": {
   "@types/node": "^13.7.1",
   "@types/react": "^16.9.19",
   "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
   "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
   "@types/yup": "^0.26.31"
 }
  }
```

Comment: Any code of your `package.json` file?

Comment: Also, please include your now config if you have one.

Comment: Are you talking about the now.json?

Answer (score 1):

Try `bash build` or `npm run build`.

That error happens if you enter only `build` in your project's settings.

Comment: Why should I build it? I just try to deploy it, it's from a template. I deployed the packages/api, works fine. But when I try to deploy packages/admin(which is a dashboard), by entering `now` then it failed

Comment: Then we really need more information. The problem you described is common when you have problems with the build configuration on https://zeit.co/blog/advanced-project-settings